# Sum an array of properties with unique object_id

Tags: ruby

Say I have the following array of objects:

```
objects = [{id: 1, installs: 21}, {id: 2, installs: 10}, {id:1, installs: 11}, {id:3, installs:5}]
```

I want to sum all `install` values for the same `id`. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Note `object_id` is a method defined on Object, so every object in Ruby has this method. Using this name as key could create confusion.

Comment: Got it - i was just using it for the sake of the example. edited the question above

Answer (score 4):

```
objects = [{id: 1, installs: 21}, {id: 2, installs: 10}, {id: 1, installs: 11}, {id: 3, installs: 5}]

sums = Hash.new(0)  # sums returns 0 for an unknown key
objects.each{|h| sums[h[:id]] += h[:installs]}
p sums  # => {1=>32, 2=>10, 3=>5}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted = objects.group_by{|x|x[:id]}
sorted.map{|x|x[1].inject(0){|sum, x| sum + x[:installs]}}
```